# using Silverlight MediaElement with Absolute URI

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

I am trying to build a small silverlight application.
I've got files I am hosting on my localhost. I want to be able to use MediaElement to play them. However I keep getting this annoying error message when I launch my silverlight application:

Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application SLControls.xap
Code: 4001
Category: MediaError
Message: AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR

I am using the following line to init the MediaElement source:

Uri.TryCreate(http://localhost:/mywebsite/Data/Users/16/Channels/472.MP3, UriKind.Absolute, out Channellocation);

Thank you in advance,

Vondiplo

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is in ':' character after localhost?
Try this link:
http://localhost/mywebsite/Data/Users/16/Channels/472.MP3

You can debug network problems using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) tool.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does not support cross-scheme newtwork requests. If you creates your application from Blend 2 SP1, or choose not to generate a test ASP.NET site, by default the IDE will generate a Test page automatically and run it using the file:// scheme. Make sure that you are not using the file:// scheme, and for sure make sure that if you pasted the URL in your browser, the file is successfully located.